# set color to tabs

Tags: android, colors, tabs

I want to set color to my text HAHA. I mean it should look black. how can I do it?

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, BasicsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("intentId", 4);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("H").setIndicator("HAHA", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.hand)).setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `setIndicator()` that takes a `String` and a `Drawable`, use the version of `setIndicator()` that takes a `View`, and inflate your own layout.